# How to access notification settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

My application uses push notifications. It would be nice to show notifications status on the UI. Is it possible to read notification settings from iPhone settings application like my own application settings in settings bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]` will give you a bitmask showing whether badges, sounds, and/or alerts are enabled for your app. (Note that this setting only affects remote notifications; **local** notifications are unaffected).

Otherwise, as rckoenes points out, you can't access any settings in your app.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't access general settings from your app.